# Elimine todos mis usuarios en mysql

Tags: mysql

Como puedo agregar nuevamente un usuario root tengo uno pero no tiene nada de privilegios para crear algo, estoy apenas iniciando con mysql y quería conectarlo a java por error elimine todo.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes un usuario, pero no tienes los permisos puedes asignarselos en ves de estar creando uno nuevo.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'localhost';
```

Con eso otorgaras todos los permisos de administrador al usuario que asignes en la parte nombre_usuario. Sin embargo, si te quieres igualmente crear un usuario nuevo puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma y luego asignas los permisos.

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```